# Is Java Swing's text API suited for displaying automatically generated text?

Tags: java, swing, parsing, document

(short summary at the bottom)

Hello,

I'm writing a tool in Java that's used to examine a binary file. Due to the format of the data, I can't parse the file in a linear way. Instead, I have to jump a lot through the entire file. While examining it, I'm filling a data structure that annotates each offset in the file with the required information. All the annotations are strings. Some should have a different color and an ability to interact with them, e.g. right clicking with custom actions depending on the type.

So basically, I'm parsing the file into a map-like structure, adding nodes and leaves at non-predictable locations. I want to display the contents as linear text, sorted by the offset in the binary file. The user should be able to work with the parsed content while other parts of the file are still being parsed, so waiting for the parsing to be done and then doing a linear insert is not an option. The user will never change any part of the text, so I don't need undo-actions etc.

I've looked at Swing's Text API, some of the features I need seem to be present there, e.g. using different View objects to be able to interact with some of the texts. However, I've looked at the source and it seems that Swing Documents have an underlying Content class that store the entire text. While memory is not a concern, I'm worried about the performance of inserting the text at random locations while parsing the document. The GapContent class (which is the default implementation of a Document's Content interface) is suited for multiple edits at the same location, so inserts at random positions would cause a lot of array copies to happen.

I thought about other options, but since I've never used Swing's text API before, I need some advice whether any of the ideas is good:

a) Implementing AbstractDocument.Content myself. The problem would be that Swing uses offsets in a "virtual" text file, so I'd have to remember which offset in Swing's world belongs to which node in my structure. Changing the structure while parsing will make this approach rather complex.

b) Implementing the whole Document interface myself. I'm not sure if that would lead to the same problem as in option a.

c) Using the structure I already have and creating a completely custom Swing component for it. This also sounds complex because I want a text-editor-like feeling for the user. But at least I wouldn't have to introduce virtual text offsets and could just insert views for each line that's added.

So in short:

- I'm parsing a binary file and annotate some addresses in the file with a list of strings (lines)
- new annotations will be made at unpredictable addresses while parsing
- I already have a way to ask for all annotations at a certain address, i.e. the strings are stored in my structure already. An observer receives changes with the actual offset in the binary file.
- I need a way to display a text representation of the structure that get updates when the structure gets updates
- The user will never edit the text, but some words should be right-clickable

Comment: Ah amigo. This isn't really stackoverflow ready. Just seems too broad I think. but basically, Java can do most anything

Comment: The specific problem is: I have a class that I can ask about string lines for a given offset. Observers get notified when lines for an offset change. How do I display this class in a "live" manner so that everything is in correct order even though the addresses are changed randomly?

Comment: _I want a text-editor-like feeling…The user will never edit the text_?

Comment: @trashgod I meant that it should look like a text editor and the use should be able to mark text, copy and paste it - but not modify it.

Comment: You'll have a lot _more_ work to do if you _don't_ use `javax.swing.text`.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize WatchEvent to listen any change on your file. You could reference the official document for detail at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: Changes to the file are not the problem. I already have an interface for the whole file - including an observer that notifies me of changed offsets. I just don't know how to display the textual representation because Swing's Content class is not suited for doing lots of changes at random locations.

Comment: No, Swing components such as JLabel, JTextArea are capable of changing words on demand. For example, myJTextArea.setText(newTextString). In addition, please handle threading carefully, such as using SwingUtilities.invokeLaterSwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ public void run() { // text update } });

Comment: Right. But I'm talking about adding thousands of lines to a JEditorPane in a random order, i.e. the underlying Content class has to handle a lot of updates. It's gonna be really slow because the default Content implementation is suited for handling updates to related positions. The question is whether I should still use the Document class (maybe implementing a custom Content implementation) or do something on my own.